# Getting connection refused only for ec2 Redhat Enterprise Linux 6.4 64 bit

Tags: redhat, ec2-ami

I am getting connection refused error while connection to the redhat instance via putty. The steps that i followed are as follows
Created a EBS backed redhat instance (with only root volume) from public AMI for redhat Enterprise Linux 6.4 (64 bit)
Rebooted the instance, and tried connecting to it via putty, connected successfully
Created a pvt ami from the instance (with only root volume) and then launched an instance from my private ami
Tried connecting to it, via ssh , connection successful
Rebooted the instance, and tried connecting to it, it started giving connection refused

Just to ensure that i am not doing anything wrong, I tried the same set of steps for Ubuntu, I was able to connect to it successfully.

I tried doing a little debugging, in the boot.log, all the services started successfully except sshd, here is a piece from boot.log

Starting cloud-init: Cloud-init v. 0.7.1 running 'modules:config' at Thu, 01 Aug 2013 16:09:51 +0000. Up 20.02 seconds.
Starting cloud-init: Cloud-init v. 0.7.1 running 'modules:final' at Thu, 01 Aug 2013 16:09:52 +0000. Up 20.43 seconds.
Cloud-init v. 0.7.1 finished at Thu, 01 Aug 2013 16:09:52 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2. Up 20.56 seconds
Starting sshd: FAILED
Starting postfix: OK 
Starting abrt daemon: OK

the messages log shows :
Aug 1 12:09:46 ip-10-165-20-194 kernel: PCI: Fatal: No config space access function found

I am unable to figure out the problem, if required i will post the content of all the logs

Thanks
Vishvadeepak Tewari

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get a reply from aws folks.
attaching the url for reply for helping others
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=475492